# How to use wildcard in elastic query?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-30m/m"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "Name": "*Rajesh*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "Name": "*Shiv*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want search in the name field using wildcard that matches any of the two wildcard values (*Rajesh*,*Shiv*).And i need to look tat the results from last 30 minutes. When i am using this wildcard, it does not give me any result. Replacing 'Wildcard' with 'match' worked though . like "match" :"Rajesh" or "match" :"Shiv". Is there something wrong with usage of wildcard in my query ?

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match as well as your index mappings and settings?

Comment: @sweta were u able to solve the issue or figure out the mapping?

Comment: Thanks for asking @OpsterElasticsearchNinja. No was not able to solve it using wildcard. But i have used 'match' for all the various combinations i would get in name field

Answer (score 0):

Most probably cause of the error is that you are using `text` field to store the names like `Rajeash` and `Shiv` and `text` fields by default uses the standard analyzer which lowercase the generated tokens so tokens would be creates as `rajesh` and `shiv`. **Note the lowercase in the tokens.**

When you use the `match` query, it uses the same analyzer so again it search with lowercase tokens and you get the result while wildcard query you are specifying the capital letter which doesn't matches the tokens in index.

change your wildcard query to `*rajesh*` and `*shiv*` and it should work, otherwise provide the mapping to further debug the issue.